# Is it possible to freeze Eggplant Parmesan? If so, better to freeze before or after baking?

Tags: freezing, cheese, eggplant, cream-cheese, parmesan

I made a delicious eggplant parmesan dish last night and now my wife wants to repeat it and then freeze it for another occasion.

What's the best advice for freezing it? Is it better to freeze it before or after baked?

Here are the ingredients: eggplants pre-baked so they are soft, tomato sauce with green peppers and a sliced fresh tomato, paste of Quark Cream Cheese mixed with olive oil and fresh basil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have frozen eggplant Parmesan before with good results. I breaded the eggplant, fried it, then put Parmesan on top while it was still hot enough to melt. I let them cool and then froze the fried eggplant slices separated by pieces of parchment paper. When I needed to use them, I put them on a sheet pan, still frozen, and threw them in the oven until the cheese was melted and slightly browned, then proceeded as I normally would.

Comment: So, you cook it directly from frozen? Is that better than thawing and then cooking?

Comment: @samyb8 baking them directly from frozen avoids condensation and frost sogginess that can occur if you thaw then bake. It keeps the breading nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this dish is ideal for freezing, but if you choose to do so, per [Martha Stewart](http://www.marthastewart.com/336836/eggplant-parmesan):

> To Freeze: Assemble dish but do not bake; wrap tightly with foil and
>   freeze, up to 3 months. Thaw completely, then bake as directed.

Comment: Is it better to thaw before putting in the oven? Or would it be more efficient to put it frozen in the oven to avoid having too much liquid coming out?

Answer (score 1):

I have had success breading eggplant and freezing it raw. You can then fry the eggplant (no need to even thaw) when it is time to construct your dish. With a little pre-prepared sauce in the freezer too you can have a scratch made eggplant parmigiano in approx. 15-20 mins.